# How to warm up EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

The first query of EF Core is very slow cause EF need to map entities, load assemblies etc. For example, first query is executed for 700ms whe the next ones for 20ms.
How to warm up the EF on the start of application?

Comment: One option is to "warm up" the other is to find out why there's any delay. Are the contexts *too big* perhaps? A context isn't a full data model, it should only contain as many entities as needed to cover a specific scenario. It's OK to have multiple contexts that may even reuse classes or tables

Comment: As for why EF is slow, it's because it needs to check and perform migrations (disable that if you don't want it to). EF Core doesn't generate views, so there's no such delay. The *database server* caches data too, so the first query will always run slower than subsequent ones that benefit from cached data.

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov this won't help - EF Core doesn't generate views

Comment: I'd suggest profiling your application to see what's *really* slowing things down. If you have a web application, add eg MiniProfiler and check what time is spent in different parts of the application. If you target SQL Server you could use Extended Events to trace calls in an inexpensive manner and see eg whether EF Core is performing migrations. You can also configure EF Core to use .NET Core's logging and log detailed actions.

Comment: I think you should call Database.EnsureCreated or Database.Migrate method.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Context contains 40 tables - not too big. Check for new migration is performed before first queries on the start of application (desktop app). I've already proffiled the application and found that the problem in a linq query that run very slow first time. I saw solution for EF 6 to create xml file with mapping of fields, but I can't do this for EF Core

Comment: @WhoKnows that's *way* too big. Do you really use *all* of them in a single query, form or operation? Do you need *all* of them in every form? That's like saying you have a class with 40 complex properties `which isn't too big`. Btw, that's just what the DbContext is. With a normal class you'd say `this is too big` and break it apart

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, I mean database has 40 tables, but query join only 3-4 tables. Even queries without join run very slow for first run.

Comment: @WhoKnows the database can have thousands of tables. The *context* shouldn't. The query shouldn't join anything either, that's the ORM's job. The *ORM* generates joins from the navigation properties and relations specified on the entities. Even *one* join is a smell - it means a relation was missed or was too hard to represent

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you missunderstood me. Please, create db with one table and 100 records and try to get all records. Your firsst query would be 50ms for example, the next ones would be 3ms. The same situation with insert or update so the problem not in caching results.

Comment: @WhoKnows that's *exactly* how caching behaves. First query hits a cold database server which has to read everything in memory. The next ones hit the memory buffers. INSERTs and updates are affected by buffering too - the server has to find the records to update. That's why you may run a query in SSMS multiple times and get *faster* performance for every subsequent execution.

Comment: @WhoKnows another reason for the "delay" may be the very act of connecting to the database. Connecting and authenticating takes time, which is why connection pooling is used. The first query you make through ADO.NET will have to establish a connection. Every subsequent one though will pick an already created connection from the connection pool. You could set a minimum connection pool size, perhaps even open/close a connection at startup, to "warm" the connection pool and avoid paying that cost the first time a query runs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it makes sense but most of this time EF spend on mapping enities, fk on first query to entity and It is well-known problem in EF but I don't know how to resolve it in EF Core. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4372

Comment: @WhoKnows a lot of what you linked to doesn't apply. EF Core doesn't generate views. EF Core 2.2 is *very* different from the EF Core preview issue you linked to - they even call it EF 7. As for mapping entities, that's the time spent inside a context's. A far more interesting issue is [the followup](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1906) that shows that some things are a lot better in EF Core 2.1, some are still slow

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What would you suggest to do to improve first query speed? It is very important for desktop application to load data as fast as possible after every restart. Because now on a weak computer we wait 2 sec for first insert query and then only 100ms huge difference.

Comment: @WhoKnows Theres not much you can do. If its absolute performance you need then, maybe something more light weight like `Dapper` or the raw connector is something you want to consider.